# Concatenate Unique Values without counting blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate unique values from a row. I found VBA code online but it counts blank cells as a unique value.

How can I alter the code so it doesn't count blank cells?

```vb
Function ConcatUniq(xRg As Range, xChar As String) As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xDic As Object
    Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty
    Next
    ConcatUniq = Join$(xDic.Keys, xChar)
    Set xDic = Nothing
End Function
```

(Original code from [ExtendOffice](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3418-excel-concatenate-unique-values.html))

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel you do not need vba at all. What version have you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `If` statement with `IsEmpty`

`If Not IsEmpty(xCell) Then xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty` as a test

You may wish to add a `<> vbNullString` comparison as well in case you want to exclude cells containing `""`.

```
If Not IsEmpty(xCell) And xCell.Value <> vbNullString Then xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, worked great. But I did run into the exact problem you mentioned (cells containing " ") being picked up and I tried (and failed) to alter the code with <> vbNullString (I did try :/). A quick help there too if you wouldnt mine plz? Cheer