# Unique Concat list excluding errors and blanks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to obtain concatenated unique values in a column that has both blanks and errors (i.e. N/A or Div1/0). Trying to make the concatenation skip errors but it is not working and the concat function just returns #VALUE error. Used the code from [Concatenate Unique Values without counting blank cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273119/concatenate-unique-values-without-counting-blank-cells). I've tried multiple solutions such as adding AND NOT Iserror(xCell.value), xcell.value <> "#N/A", xcell.value <> CVErr(xlErrNA), NOT worksheetfunction.isna(xcell). None of it works.

```
Function ConcatUniq(xRg As Range, xChar As String) As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xDic As Object
    Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If Not IsEmpty(xCell) And xCell.Value <> vbNullString Then xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty
    Next
    ConcatUniq = Join$(xDic.Keys, xChar)
    Set xDic = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: May I ask, also as per linked post, what version of Excel you are using? Why create functions if they may be readily available for you?

Comment: Did you ever hear of the `=UNIQUE()` function?

Comment: It's excel 2016 :( so i can't use unique and textjoin function

Answer (score 2):

For me the following worked:

```
For Each xCell In xRg
    If Not IsError(xCell.Value) And Not IsEmpty(xCell) Then xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you know why adding an additional and statement of And xCell.Value <> vbNullString would break the code?

Comment: Probabaly simply because the error in the cell @zhangsterali. Btw, if it has worked, don't forget to accept the anser by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.